# Magento subcategories are showing

Tags: magento

We have one e-commerce website in magento. Its categories are displaying in the menu bar. But sub-categories are not displaying. I have set the visible menu depth to zero. We are using smartwave porto theme. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: can you tell me which magento version you used?

Comment: magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: can you share admin details?

Comment: Sorry. Its our live website.

Comment: send me admin category parts screen short

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: is it working or not?

Comment: @Jinesh I have included the admin category

Comment: have you check my answer?and can you give screen short of sub category setting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following step :-

```
Add new cateogry and necessary subcategories for dropdown content.

Select the menu item that you just created, and go to "Menu" tab.

Choose "Menu Type" field as "Classic".
```

Comment: I have created on new category and one subcategory. Only the category is showing.

Comment: can you share sub category selection?

Comment: How can I add image in comment?

Comment: you can send me in my email id.my email id "jscatoz@gmail.com"

Comment: I have sent an Hi in your gtalk